# nginx does not work for my public IP

Tags: linux, nginx, ip

I just installed nginx on my linux machine. I haven't even changed any of the default configurations yet I get no response when trying to call the server from my own public IP address. It works when calling localhost / private machine IP. The default file from /sites-available:

```
server {
    listen *:80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

curl response on public IP:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 89.x.x.x port 80: Connection refused
```

I tried disabling ufw firewall / enabling ports on it and nothing works. Can anyone point me into right direction?

Comment: Please add information about your network topology.

Comment: Does your public IP point directly to your server? If your server is behind a router your need to configure port forwarding.